# SQL count and distinct and partition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying out some examples with analytical functions and i have created a sql fiddle to understand a count distinct over partition by clause.This is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/510f7/3).

```
create table dummy (value1 varchar2(10),value2 varchar2(10));

insert into dummy values ('abc','abc1');
insert into dummy values ('abc','abc1');
insert into dummy values ('abc','abc2');
insert into dummy values ('def','abc1');
insert into dummy values ('ghi','abc2');
insert into dummy values ('xyz','abc3');
insert into dummy values ('xyz','abc3');

select value1,
       value2,
       count(distinct value2) over (partition by value1) as ValCount
from dummy
```

If you look at the result set, i would expect valcount as 1 for the third row but instead its 2 and am not sure why that's the case.

Comment: should the valcount not be 1? because for value1 abc, there is only one abc2 ?

Comment: yes..you are right..i think i was thinking too much..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

abc (value 1) has only 2 distinct values on the second column (abc1 and abc2), and since you count the distinct values on column2 partitioned over column 1 you should indeed get 2

Answer (score 1):

The valcount should be 2.

You've partitioned by value1, so the count executes within that context.  That is to say, in the group of results where value1 = "abc", there are 2 distinct values of value2 ("abc1", "abc2").